# how to get multiple records from db and put into array or map

Tags: arrays, maps, elixir

I want to get multiple records from db and put into array or map.

this is my sample array with user ids

```
{"array":[133,136,137] }
```

this is my code

```
def array(conn, %{"array" => array}) do
      userlist = %{}
      Enum.each(array, fn(x) ->
         Map.put(userlist, x, Repo.get(ApiDb.User, x))
      end)
      json conn, userlist
  end
```

but this method return empty array

below is the console output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this approach is more optimized than @Dogbert's one (correct me if I'm wrong) because we ask directly Ecto to format each row in tuple then we convert the list of tuples into a map using the built-in `Enum.into/2`. For that, you'll want to import `Ecto.Query` in your current module and :

```
query = from user in ApiDb.User,
        where: user.id in ^user_ids, 
        select: {user.id, user}

Repo.all(query) |> Enum.into(%{})
```

which yields

`%{id1 => user1, id2 => user2...}`

For the Poison encoding problem, I didn't encounter any problem regarding the conversion of number keys, as they get converted into strings automatically by Poison.

Hope this also helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the value of a variable outside `Enum.each` from within `Enum.each`. For this specific case, I'd use a `for` to iterate through the list, fetch the user, and put it in a map with the id as key:

```
def array(conn, %{"array" => array}) do
  users = for x <- array, into: %{}, do: {"#{x}", Repo.get(ApiDb.User, x)}
  json conn, users
end
```

I'd suggest using `id IN _` query here so that all the records are fetched in a single query:

```
def array(conn, %{"array" => array}) do
  users = from(u in ApiDb.User, where: u.id in ^array) |> Repo.all
  map = for user <- users, into: %{}, do: {"#{user.id}", user}
  json conn, map
end
```

Comment: both getting ** (Poison.EncodeError) expected string or atom key, got: 133 error.

i have that Poison.Encoder in lib folder .

defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Any do
  def encode(%{__struct__: _} = struct, options) do
    map = struct
          |> Map.from_struct
          |> sanitize_map
          |> Poison.Encoder.Map.encode(options)
    #Poison.Encoder.Map.encode(map, options)
  end

  defp sanitize_map(map) do
    Map.drop(map, [:__meta__, :__struct__])
  end
end

Comment: I've updated the answer to convert the keys to strings. That should work. Let me know.